# Finding the mode out of a set of values from a HashMap, break ties by indicating no mode at all

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

The HashMap would look like:

```
Keys: 1, 2, 4

Values: 1, 2, 1
```

The mode here would be 2, since it's value is the highest out of the set of values.

However, if

```
Keys: 1, 2, 4

Values: 1, 2, 2
```

Then there's no mode. I get the expected output for the smaller test cases I have, but not sure if there's a logic error here that wouldn't work for larger outputs / if the values are very large and wouldn't fit in an Integer.

"count" is the HashMap.

My code:

```
            for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
                int curr = entry.getValue();
                if (curr > mode) {
                    mode = curr;
                }
                else if (curr == mode) {
                    mode = -1;
                }
            }

            if (mode != -1) {
                for (HashMap.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : count.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue() == mode) {
                        mode = entry.getKey();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Isn't the _mode_ typically defined as the most common value? So in your examples, it would be `1` and `2` respectively.

Comment: No. The value is the frequency of the key. The first example would be 2, since its value is 2, the max of the set of values. The second example would be no mode, because there's a tie for max of the set of values.

Comment: Ah, I see. I misunderstood your data structure. Carry on.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please add declaration and assignment of `diffs` variables. And please edit your question to show for which input you are getting incorrect output and what the expected output is.

Comment: Check the edits

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work for this input:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
count.put(1, 2);
count.put(2, 2);
count.put(4, 1);
```

because you are setting `mode = -1` as soon as you find a duplicate instead of doing it at the end.

You can try the following code which makes 2 passes on the EntrySet. Once to find the max value and then to retrieve the entries having that max value.

```
Integer max = count.values().stream()
        .max(Integer::compareTo)
        .orElse(-1);
List<Integer> maxEntries = count.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(max))
        .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
Integer mode = maxEntries.size() == 1 ? maxEntries.get(0) : -1; //if there is a tie, mode is -1
System.out.println(mode);
```

To be able to store values bigger than `Integer`, you can use `Long` and `BigInteger`.

Answer (score 0):

As Kartik has already said, you are correct, there’s are bugs in your code. There’s also one in the loop in the end: you need to break out of it as soon as you have found the key corresponding to the value, or `mode` may be altered again in a later iteration leading to an incorrect result. For example

```
new HashMap<>(Map.of(1, 3, 2, 1))
```

In this case you code will correctly determine that the highest count is 3. The loop to find the corresponding key will first change 3 to 1 and next time 1 to 2. So the result is 2, which is incorrect. The basic problem is that you are using the same variable, `mode`, for two purposes, first the count of the mode, next the kay of the mode. Don’t do that. The risk of confusion is too high.

I should like to give my shot at a solution:

```
public static OptionalInt getModeIfUnique(Map<Integer, Integer> count) {
    Optional<Integer> maxCount = count.values().stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    OptionalInt modeKey = maxCount.flatMap(mc -> {
                        // Map containing only the entries having max count
                        Map<Integer, Integer> allModes = new HashMap<>(count);
                        allModes.values().removeIf(c -> c < mc);
                        if (allModes.size() == 1) {
                            return Optional.of(allModes.keySet().iterator().next());
                        } else {
                            return Optional.empty();
                        }
                    })
            .map(OptionalInt::of)
            .orElse(OptionalInt.empty());
    return modeKey;
}
```

Trying it out:

```
    // Kartik’s example - should give no mode
    System.out.println(getModeIfUnique(Map.of(1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1)));
    // My example - should give 1
    System.out.println(getModeIfUnique(Map.of(1, 3, 2, 1)));
    // Empty map - should give no mode
    System.out.println(getModeIfUnique(Map.of()));
```

Output:

> ```
> OptionalInt.empty
> OptionalInt[1]
> OptionalInt.empty
> ```

Comment: If I may, I'd like to suggest changing `OptionalInt` to `Optional`. Reason#1 - It will prevent auto-unboxing of elements. The resulting code takes less than half the time for a map of size 3. Performance gain will be much bigger for bigger maps. Reason#2 - You'll be able to get rid of the last 2 lines `.map(..).orElse(..)`. Reason#3 - The word "Optional" is a bit more concise than "OptionalInt". :)

Comment: Also, since we're using Integer wrapper class, it should be `!c.equals(mc)` instead of `c != mc`.

Comment: Thanks. I edited to use `<` to ensure unboxing. You may prefer `removeIf(c -> c.intValue() < mc.intValue())`. For `Optional<Integer>`, I see the point, but I think we should first of all let it rely on what is more convenient for the caller.